# Good firewall for Vista?

Tags: firewall, windows-vista

I just bought my first laptop. It runs Vista, and I need a software firewall to protect both its Ethernet and wifi connections.

I use the free Comodo Personal Firewall on my desktop, but I read that wifi protection requires upgrading to the commercial version.

Before I shell out the money, I'd like to know
1. what the recommended firewalls are for Vista
2. among those, are there free/open-source options?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need that the built-in firewall doesn't do?

Comment: What are you using for antivirus?  I'd be more concerned about that and just use the built-in firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Firewall and Windows Defender (wich is builtin) is fine.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the firewall Microsoft is shipping. Windows firewall is really ok.

Comment: Everyone put your Ipods down and listin up!

Comment: So, you mean it does more than the crappy Windows XP one? That's good news!

Answer (score 0):

Until Windows included its own built in I used to use Zonealarm, which handles both incoming and outgoing connections.  And its free as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific requirements.  Using the baked-in vista one has the advantage of letting windows installer open ports when a vista aware application requires them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fine-grained control you could use ipsec? start->run->secpol.msc, then go to the bottom one in the list (IP Security Policies). I've managed to lock myself out of remote machines regularly with that one, so I guess that should suffice? ;-)